# Spring boot integration XXE prevention settings

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, xxe

We have an application in spring boot+spring integration and we are trying to introduce the XXE attack prevention.

In java code we can make the changes as per the below link https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#SAXTransformerFactory

I have the sample working example in [github](https://github.com/nvijaykarthik/spring-integration-xml-jms-sample) where the application uses the active mq as queue manager. 
[sample input xml](https://github.com/nvijaykarthik/spring-integration-xml-jms-sample/blob/master/order.xml)

What kind of changes i can make in the above sample to enable the XXE prevention.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Spring Integration versions 4.3.18, 5.0.10, 5.1.2 and later have those options set by default in the transformer factory etc. Or you can inject a custom-created instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a general answer. . .
You can simply introduce your own implementation of the transformer as a bean instead of using the provided XSLT transformer

```
<int:transformer. . .>
   <bean class=".."/>
</int:transformer>
```

This way you have full control with regard to these type of customizations

Comment: Thank you very much we will try this, I am planning to override the DocumentBuilderFactory settings in DefaultXmlPayloadConverter so that not only XSLT transformer even the String to DOM converter can also utilize this.   Your thoughts on this please

Comment: Spring Integration versions 4.3.18, 5.0.10, 5.1.2 and later have those options set by default in the transformer factory etc. Or you can inject a custom-created instance.

Comment: Thank you, we will upgrade the versions